# Android get the app component from getIntent()

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Okay I got my **Application** and my **MainActivity**. When the user presses my app icon my application launches and **MainActivity** gets created. Now in ***onCreate()*** with ***getIntent()*** method can i get the Android System component(the class name) which started my activity??

Answer (score 2):

You can get class name by using this code.`getClass().getName()`

In getIntent() you receive parse variable throw intent.